# Windows 8.1 Device Manager now showing ACER Device rather than Android Device for Google Nexus 7

Tags: android

During a Windows Update this week I was presented with an optional patch titled "Other hardware - ACER Composite ADB Interface". This was part of a larger patch update, and I wrongly ticked and installed the patch. I do not own any Acer kit, but I do use [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) in wider Android development.

When I connect my tablet to the PC now it shows up in Device Manager inside a container named "ACER Device" with the title "ACER Composite ADB Interface". It is not visible to either the PC or ADB. Previously it appeared in a container called "Android Device" and worked fine. The device is a Google Nexus 7.

Annoyingly the patch is not listed in installed programs or installed updates, and I am struggling to try and remove it. I've already tried to uninstall the device (and drivers), but these just get reloaded when the device is plugged back in.

How do I remove this patch?

Comment: Please forward your question to http://superuser.com/

Comment: Have you tried just right clicking the device in device manager and selecting update driver then browse to the Google USB Driver (If you don't have it you can download it)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. Also removed the device and it's drivers through Device Manager and if you are quick it comes back as Android Device before switching to ACER Device. I tried the driver update in this state with the same result.

Answer (score 100):

First try this simple procedure provided by @volodymyr-rybak:

> Open 'ACER Composite ADB Interface' and select 'Update Driver...', in
> the opened window select 'Browse my computer for driver software' then
> 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer' in the list
> select 'MTP USB Device' and click on Next button.

---

This is what worked for my Nexus 4.

1. Disconnect your Android device.
2. Disable USB Debugging in Developer Options.
3. In the Device Manager (on PC), click on `View --> Show Hidden Devices`.
4. Double click on the entry for `ACER Composite ADB Interface` to open `Properties`.

   Click on the `Driver` tab and then on `Roll Back Driver`. This will uninstall the problematic drivers.

   If the 'Roll Back Driver' option is grayed out, then click `Uninstall`. In the confirmation pop up window, select `Delete the driver software for this device` and then click OK.
5. Do this for all the instances of 'ACER Composite ADB Interface'.
6. Shut down your PC. And start it again.
7. Now reconnect your device. Your PC will recognize it as a storage device.
8. Re-enable USB Debugging.
9. If it again shows up as 'ACER Composite ADB Interface', then repeat (4) and (5) to roll back the driver update.
10. Or... Open 'ACER Composite ADB Interface' and select 'Update Driver...', in the opened window select 'Browse my computer for driver software' then 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer' in the list select 'MTP USB Device' and click on Next button.

Comment: After win8.1 update my Nexus5 was not mounting correctly anymore and showing up in device manager as "ACER ADB Interface". This procedure fixed the problem.

Comment: I just purchased an Acer laptop and am trying to attach my Nexus 5 to do debugging, and having this problem. But this solution doesn't work for me. The Roll Back Driver option is always disabled, and Uninstall seems to just uninstall the device until it's connected again.

Comment: @tyrel, make sure that you shut down your laptop (instead of a restart) (step 6). System Restore is your last available option.

Comment: @dnp thanks, that did the trick! It was so frustrating because for a while it would start out showing as the "Android" device and then about 10-30 seconds later would suddenly swap to the "Acer" device. Anyway, all good now!

Comment: +1 FWIW, option 10. was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: worked for me, I had to do step 9 after the restart.

Comment: Updating the driver worked for my Nexus 5. The only difference was that instead of MTP USB Device, I had to choose Composite USB Device. Thanks!

Comment: The way I solve it: First, I unplug my Nexus 6. I just uninstalled the "ACER Composite ADB Interface" Driver, downloaded the latest Google USB from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html. Extract the files and right click on "android_winusb.inf" and click on install. After it is done, I plug Nexus back in. Then it works. Now the device should show "Adnroid Composite ADB Interface". Good luck guys.

Comment: Clement Ho's addition was required for me. I was getting a driver-less Nexus 4 under Other Devices. That had to have the google driver installed. You might already have it in your SDK tree.

Comment: "Delete the driver software for this device" worked for me

Comment: The method of @volodymyr-rybak worked seamlessly for me. God bless him. No need to uninstall the ACER ADB driver. :)

Answer (score 20):

If the problem persists, right-click the ACER ADB Interface and select 'Update driver...', then 'Browse my computer...' then '**Let me pick from a list...**' and you should see two options for the Nexus, Google Nexus ADB Interface and another called **MTP USB Device**. Choose MTP and hit 'Next' to install the driver, then it should show up as a portable device on your computer.

Comment: After upgrading to Android Lollipop, the problem persisted. This solved it for me on Windows 8.1

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I use both Nexus 7 and Nexus 5 on box so there was some problem.  I followed the suggested procedure to resolve the issue. Connected my Nexus 5 in "MTP" mode


1. Opened Device Manager

2. Right clicked on "Acer Device" - "Acer Composite ADB interface" -> "Update Driver Software"

3. Then Selected "Browse my computer for driver software"

4. Then Selected "Let me pickup from a list" and selected the non Acer one and voila it worked.

Comment: Your method worked for me on Windows 10, but only after first disabling the device (right click -> disable, in device manager).

Answer (score 3):

To uninstall the ACER driver and remove the driver files:

(Re)connect your Nexus 7 to your computer. Open Device Manager (you can search for it from the Windows Control Panel).

Locate and expand an entry named "Android Device." The Nexus 7 should show up as either "Android Composite ADB Interface" or "ACER Composite ADB Interface" under "Android Device."

Right-click the entry and select "Properties." Under the "Driver" tab, select the last entry, "Uninstall." In the new dialog window that appears, check "Delete the driver software for this device." Click OK to uninstall the ACER driver and remove the driver files.

Make sure the current version of the Google Nexus USB driver is installed:

Download the latest version of the USB driver from the Android Developer pages and unzip it on your desktop. A folder named "usb_driver" will be created.

In Device Manager, locate your Nexus 7 again under "Android Device," richt-click and choose "Update Driver Software..." This launches the Hardware Update Wizard.

Choose "Browse my computer for driver software." Browse to the location of the "usb_driver" folder on your desktop and check "include subfolders." Then click OK. The current Google Nexus Driver will now be installed.

Note: If the Hardware Wizard reports that "the best driver software is already installed," simply repeat the steps to uninstall the current driver for the Nexus 7 as described above, then try and install the current Google Nexus driver again.

Answer (score 0):

My Windows 8.1 PC did the automatic update which included the "ACER ADB Interface update for Windows 8.1" drivers. This happened while I was away and this afternoon when I came home I was asked to re-boot the PC to enable updates to be applied.

Since the updates were applied I have not been able to connect my Nexus 7 (2012) as a "MTP USB Device". I have spent hours trying to find a solution including doing a factory re-set on the tablet.

The tablet connected successfully before I went away! That was a clue. So I did a Windows Restore to an earlier restore point. What do you know? The Nexus 7 now connected just like it did before.

I then checked for Windows Updates but carefully looked at what was being updated. The ACER ADB update was listed as an "additional update". I have marked it to be forgotten and then applied the other updates. So far so good.

So after all that; try restoring your system to an earlier restore point and select not to install the ACER ADB update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help - I'd already tried all of what was suggested apart from the System Restore which I have now done.

I left a few other things that needed fixing, but it did restore the registry and patch state to a point before I applied the ACER patch, and I've now got things back as they were.

I have marked this patch as hidden, so it doesn't get applied again in error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, rolling back the driver for "ACER Composite ADB Interface" (which appeared under something like "ACER device") did the job. Right after rollback, without reboot, Nexus 7 appeared both in Device Manager and in File Explorer as Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case. I guess this problem is a conflict with Samsung Nexus vs LG nexus. Before I had used Samsung Nexus Galaxy. I am using LG nexus 5, now.

In my case:

1. I found the driver files and removed those. (Device Manger - ACER ADB Interface [right click]Properties - [Tab]Driver - Driver Details)
2. I also removed the device in Device Manager.
3. Then, I scanned for hardware changes.. (the driver did install with auto by Windows 8.1)

At last, I can now browse the Nexus as storage.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I selected "Uninstall" from Device Manager, unplugged the device, and re-connected.  Windows 7 itself was smart enough to find the actual driver for it and lets me use it again.

Answer (score 0):

On your device, make sure that the USB computer connection is set to “Media device (MTP).”

```
Touch Settings > Device > Storage. Then touch Menu Menu > USB computer connection. MTP should be selected by default, but you may have to uncheck MTP, check and uncheck Camera (PTP), and then recheck MTP.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither updating the driver nor a windows system restore help. When I tried with a different USB cable, the system detected my Nexus 5 device. For some reason the other USB cable while charging the phone does NOT show the device at all even now.

PS: I wanted to try with a different USB cable than the one I had but unfortunately could not get hold of one, wasted close to two hours trying all other possible solution.